# ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload - Dynamic controls created in the AsyncFileUpload1_UploadComplete() is not rendering to page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using a ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload  that allows the user to upload a excel file. In the AsyncFileUpload1_UploadComplete() event, I am reading the excel data and creating excel structure using div and adding to the page. But these dynamically created controls are not being added to the page. I added a button in the updatepanel and checked. On button click event, I created same above controls. In this case, the controls are rendering to the page. The controls are not rendering in case of ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload only. Can anybody please tell me what is the fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add Button into UpdatePanel where you want to show new controls and make it invisible with css style.
In the `AsyncFileUpload1_UploadComplete` server-side method, save your data to Session state. 
In the client-side `OnClientUploadComplete` event handler call `__doPostBack` function with hidden button's UniqueID first parameter value. Then make all stuff required to render dynamic content in that button's click handler.

Comment: Sorry for very delayed response. I will try this fix and update here.